# Not all public classes available in NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, reference, nuget, nuget-package

When I use the `dotnet pack -c Release` command to create a NuGet package and reference it in another project, not all my classes are available.
However when I create it using the `Debug` flag instead of `Release` then it works fine.

I have the following file (name DTOs.cs) which contains a lot of classes.

```cs
namespace AAUTOGateway.Models
{
    public class Unit
    {
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.15.10.0 (NJsonSchema v10.6.10.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
    public enum ConfigurationAssetType
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Asset")]
        Asset = 0,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"ContactPerson")]
        ContactPerson = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember(Value = @"Credential")]
        Credential = 2,

    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.15.10.0 (NJsonSchema v10.6.10.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
    public class ConfigurationSchemaAttributeModel
    {

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("processId")]
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("type")]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter))]
        public ConfigurationAssetType Type { get; set; }

    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.15.10.0 (NJsonSchema v10.6.10.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
    public class ConfigurationScopeAssetModel
    {

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("configurationScopeId")]
        public int ConfigurationScopeId { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("type")]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter))]
        public ConfigurationAssetType Type { get; set; }

        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
...
}
```

And the .csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Title>XXX</Title>
    <Description>XXX</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
    <Company>XXX</Company>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

However in the project, which references the NuGet package, is only able to see the `Unit` class.
[image]

Any ideas to why this is the case, or if there is something obvious that I have missed?

Comment: Maybe trimmed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: @shingo are you suggesting that the classes might be trimmed? Maybe because of the `System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode` flag, because there are also other classes which does not have that flag?

Comment: Yes. Can you confirm if these classes are really missing or just invisible to intellisense?

Comment: I just tested and re-compiling the project still results in errors `The type or namespace name 'ProcessModel' does not exist in the namespace 'AAUTOGateway.Models'`

Comment: NuGet assumes packages are globally unique and immutable. This means if you're developing a package and you test it via a PackageReference, NuGet will extract the package into the global packages folder and as long as it exists there, it will never "download" and extract the same package-version again. If you change the contents of the package without changing the version, it will keep using the "old version". So, you need to either adapt your testing methodology (for example, use semver pre-release that changes every test), or you need to delete the package from the global packages folder

Comment: @zivkan I've tested it with a version 0.0.1 which just included the Unit class. However adding all the classes and then publishing the new NuGet as a version 0.0.2 does not work either

Comment: @Theodor349 can you check with the ```NuGet Package Explorer``` whether the classes are part of the nuget?

Comment: @Silvan I used the Object Explorer in Visual Studio to check it and it can't se any of them when I bake a `Release` build, however when I make a `Debug` build then I can see all of them (I also edited the post with this new info)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212235/cant-build-release-configuration-because-of-missing-references?rq=3) are maybe some ideas.

Comment: I just tried building again today, and now it works, I have no clue why.
But maybe a restart of the system and VS did the trick?